# What is the present state of research on quantum networks?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I recently came across the article [The Quantum Internet Is Emerging, One Experiment at a Time](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-quantum-internet-is-emerging-one-experiment-at-a-time/) in Scientific American where it was discussed how quantum networks could provide a level of privacy and security impossible to achieve with classical networks.

To quote from the article:

> Although a fully realized quantum network is still a far-off vision, recent breakthroughs in transmitting, storing and manipulating quantum information have convinced some physicists that a simple proof of principle is imminent.

I am interested to know about the present state of research on quantum networking. Also, what the author of the article means by *"**a simple proof of principle**."*

Answer (score 2):

The last thing I heard about quantum communications can be seen in this [link](https://www.osa-opn.org/home/newsroom/2020/april/cavities_to_light_up_quantum_internet/). Basically, they're taking rare earth ions that can make stable, interference-resistant qubits that can travel far distances without its quantum state being modified.

This "breakthrough" in addition to the first chip-to-chip quantum teleportation performed in december, 2019 may lead to new discoveries in this matter. You can check this one out via this [link](https://phys.org/news/2019-12-chip-to-chip-quantum-teleportation-harnessing-silicon.html).

By *"**a simple proof of principle**"* I think the author means that by little experiments you can sometimes have a hint of what physical principle can be exploited to achieve a certain goal. In this context, this means that these various experiments in manipulating and transmitting qubits can be escaled up to build a global network. I guess we'll see.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links.